# Studio 3T select all array values in an array column

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I have a Mongo collection with the current schema: (simplified)

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a94615a243a426db43d81e"), 
    "property_name" : "My Main Property", 
    "domain_list" : [
        "mynumber1url.com",
        "mynumber2url.com",
        "mynumber3url.com"
    ]
}
```

I want to query this collection and return all the elements of the domain_list along with the property_name associated with it like:

```
mynumber1url.com  My Main Property
mynumber2url.com  My Main Property
mynumber3url.com  My Main Property
mynumber4url.com  My Other Property
...
```

an aggregate query would be acceptable, but I'd rather be able to do it with just a single query/projection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `$unwind` stage will be enough:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$domain_list'}
])
```

It will result in:

```
[{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("55a94615a243a426db43d81e"), 
    "property_name" : "My Main Property", 
    "domain_list" : "mynumber1url.com"
}, { 
    "_id": ObjectId("55a94615a243a426db43d81e"), 
    "property_name" : "My Main Property", 
    "domain_list" : "mynumber2url.com"
}, { 
    "_id": ObjectId("55a94615a243a426db43d81e"), 
    "property_name" : "My Main Property", 
    "domain_list" : "mynumber3url.com"
}]
```

Or if you want to have it in a single string (I'm not sure about the format):

```
db.getCollection('x').aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$domain_list'},
    {$project: {_id: {$concat: ['$property_name', ' ', '$domain_list']}}}
])
```

Which will result in:

```
[
  {"_id": "My Main Property mynumber1url.com"},
  {"_id": "My Main Property mynumber2url.com"},
  {"_id": "My Main Property mynumber3url.com"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation in 3.4.4 and after.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":
   {"$arrayToObject":{
      "$map":{
        "input":"$domain_list",
        "as":"dl",
        "in":{
         "k":"$$dl",
         "v":"$property_name"
        }
      }
    }}
  }}
])
```

Output:

```
{ 
  "mynumber1url.com" : "My Main Property", 
  "mynumber2url.com" : "My Main Property", 
  "mynumber3url.com" : "My Main Property" 
}
```